# Python Error: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected in python

Tags: java, android, sockets, python-3.x

I want to send a string from `Android` client to `python` that is server. But I found this error. Kindly guide me!

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

**Client**

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class client {

    private String serverIpAddress = "172.**.*.***";
    private boolean connected = false;
    private int serverPort = 65534;



    protected void connect() {

        if (!connected) {
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                System.out.println("server addr " +serverAddr);
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress,serverPort);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                String sendMessage = 2 + "\n";
                out.write(sendMessage);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);
                socket.close();
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
                connected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
import socket
import threading
import json

class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        print("Listening.....")

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            print("Accepted from  :: "+str(address))
            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            print ("received data:", str(data))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ThreadedServer('172.**.*.***',65534).listen()
```

I am stuck!

**Edit1** **credit:j4ck**

```
import socket
import threading
import socketserver

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = str(self.request.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
        response = bytes("{}: {}".format(cur_thread.name, data), 'ascii')
        self.request.sendall(response)

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 0

    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    print("Server loop running in thread:", server_thread.name)
```

The server is going to shut down. How to make this server alive for all requests? I want to send requests from `Android` using sockets. I want, once a request comes to server, the server should make a thread of a class not a function.

Comment: check if the implementation below helps resolve the issue. If it doesn't, it's likely a java-side issue, and you should add the `java` tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're importing the `threading` module, but do not appear to be using it at all.

I suggest you use [the `socketserver` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html), as it's a bit more convenient and does a few things for you.

The threaded version would use a `mixin` and look like this (from the python docs linked above):

```
import socket
import threading
import socketserver

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = str(self.request.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
        response = bytes("{}: {}".format(cur_thread.name, data), 'ascii')
        self.request.sendall(response)

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass  

# This is a dummy client to show the functionality and is not required, should you choose to implement it
def client(ip, port, message):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((ip, port))
        sock.sendall(bytes(message, 'ascii'))
        response = str(sock.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        print("Received: {}".format(response))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 0

    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    # Start a thread with the server -- that thread will then start one
    # more thread for each request
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    print("Server loop running in thread:", server_thread.name)

    client(ip, port, "Hello World 1")
    client(ip, port, "Hello World 2")
    client(ip, port, "Hello World 3")

    server.shutdown()
    server.server_close()
```

Comment: But I want to make server alive for all time. Once a client comes to server , server should make a new thread for the client.

Comment: if you skip `server.shutdown()` and `server.server_close()` it should run infinitely. `threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forver)` executes the `ThreadedTCPServer`'s built-in method `serve_forever()`, which does exactly what the name indicates.

Comment: See the **Edit 1** in question.